# Qt 4.7.4 Qt 5.8 QFileInfo does not work

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5, qfileinfo

I have a problem migrating my code from Qt 4.7.4 to Qt 5.8:

In my old code I use

```
void GuiUtil::setLastPath(QString path)
{
    QFileInfo finfo(path);
    if (finfo.isDir())
        GuiUtil::get()->lastPath = finfo.absoluteFilePath();
    else
        GuiUtil::get()->lastPath = finfo.absolutePath();
}
```

When I migrate this to Qt 5.8 my code compiles but **finfo** is not accessible.

Does anybody know why?

The problem is in the first line

```
QFileInfo finfo(path);
```

where from the beginning path is my directory **path = "C:/Users/s"**  type QString

After completing this line fifo is set to

```
fifo  = "C:/Users/s"  type QFileInfo  ( in Qt 4.7.4)

fifo  = ""            type QFileInfo  ( in Qt 5.8)
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Strange. What exactly do you meand with 'not accessible'. Is it an exception or is content just empty?
Anyway: I think the problem comes from your GuiUtil::get() method. Could it be, that it returns an `const QString*`? - Please post a verifiable example.

Comment: Please write a useful title for the question

Comment: Not sure why everybody puts a close on this, I see a valid question. It could be expanded to contain a minimal main-function, but sure I've seen worse questions being answered w/o close flags.

Comment: Given you have typo with fifo in your second block and should be finfo, do you see this in your debugger? The debugger sometimes can not access variables, we also had this issue. Give it a 'qDebug()<<path<<finfo.absolutePath()` and see if you get some output. Also try a complete rebuild by deleting the complete build-dir and see again.